# Is the random forest classfier affected by related samples or biological replicates?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, feature-selection, multicollinearity

Correlation or collinearity between features can impact the results of random forest. So can having unbalanced data. However, I have not found a clear answer on whether having related samples can affect the outcome of a classification analysis.

For example, if my data has biological replicates, which are individuals belonging to the same family and are genetically related, I would expect that features, e.g. measured traits, would be more correlated within families than between families, even if the features themselves aren't necessarily strongly correlated. In this case, what would be the appropriate approach? I've thought of just averaging out replicates, but the downside there is massively reducing the number of observations, which itself can have a detrimental impact on the performance of the algorithm.

Comment: Run RF with and without using samples from family members, and then you can get a handle on how kinship coefficients (degrees of relatedness) impact results.